# How to configure Okta as IDP(Identity Provider) in Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, saml, okta, ws-federation, idp

We are created an app which authenticated with ADD. Now we need to authenticated external users which authenticated with okta(idp).How can I possible to authenticate external users via azure login page. The following figure shows app flow
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define an external IdP for your AAD? Something like this [image]